# Copying multiple files into same directory while changing filename

Tags: file, powershell, copy, rename

I need to copy a series of files that look like

```
foo.bar
foo.baz
foo.boo
...
```

into the same director, but change the `foo` to `moo`.

```
moo.bar
moo.baz
moo.boo
...
```

But I'm not sure how I can copy and rename multiple files in one command. Something along the lines of

```
cp 'foo.*' . | ren foo.* moo.*
```

Except that doesn't make syntatic sense. I realize that I could put this in a temporary directory, rename there and then move it back, but I'm curious if there is a 1 line way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename multiple files in the following manner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "foo*" | {$_.name -replace 'foo','moo' }
```

Refer this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk.aspx) for more details.

And you can chain commands in powershell using a semicolon.

**EDIT:** I currently don't have access to a Windows machine to test it, but I guess the following should work:

```
ls 'foo*' | % {$newName = $_.name -replace 'foo','moo'; cp $_ $newName ; }
```

Comment: But wouldn't that replace the file? I want to keep the original copy as well.

Comment: No it won't. $newName would hold the new name you want to provide (eg: moo.bar). And then 'cp' creates a copy of the original file (ie, $_) with the name $newName. If you want to copy the file to a destination different from the current folder, you can provide that path as part of $newName.  You can first try it out with sample files to confirm it. As I mentioned, unfortunately, I'm unable to test it right now.

Comment: Oh, I meant the first attempt. the `Get-ChildItem -Filter "foo*" | {$_.name -replace 'foo','moo' }`

Comment: Actually, the first attempt might just give you an array of file names with 'foo' replaced with 'moo'. For it to actually rename the files, it would have to be something like this: Get-ChildItem -Filter "foo*" |  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace 'foo','moo' }.

Answer (score 0):

You could so it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem  -Filter "foo*" | % {
   Copy-Item  $_.Name ($_.Name -replace 'foo', 'moo' ) -WhatIf 
}
```

Leave the -whatif to test and then remove it when you happy it will give you what you want.